# Is there a command to list iex history list by batch?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

Is there a equivalent bash `history` command in `iex`?

After testing in iex, is there a way to list all history commands no need scroll up and down?

erlang history is added as follows:

```
export ERL_AFLAGS="-kernel shell_history enabled -kernel shell_history_path '\"$HOME/.iex_history\"'"
```

Comment: You do not need to set `shell_history_path` unless you are using something like docker which loses state, because it will use a [sensible default](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html#shell_history_path) anyway. In Elixir: `:filename.basedir(:user_cache, "erlang-history")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no function in `iex` to do this.

However, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to search the history.

---

By the way, `erl` has [`h()`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html#shell-commands) for this, although it seems to only list commands from the current session. It might be a nice addition to add to `iex` in the future.